# Generalization of eigenvalues/vectors to modules?

Tags: modules, ra.rings-and-algebras, eigenvector, linear-algebra, sp.spectral-theory

What is the generalization of eigenvalues/vectors to modules?

To be specific, given a "vector" v in a module over some ring, and a linear "operator" O from the module to itself (please feel free to correct my terminology :-) ), I would like to learn what we know about problems of the form

O v = k v

where k is a member of the same ring.

I have been looking through a lot of books and online resources about modules, but I am having trouble finding the answer to this question, and I am guessing that it is probably because I don't know what the name of the thing is that I should be looking for.

Edit:  Fixed a typo -- thanks Boris!  (I said that O was a map from the ring to itself when I meant it was a map from the *module* to itself.)

Update:  To be clear, I would also be happy with an answer of the form: there is not a good generalization of eigenevalues for modules with no additional structure at all, but there is if you can assume the additional structure X, where X is, say, a dot product, a norm, an involution operator, etc.

Comment: I don't really understand your question (in fact, I do not see what the question is!). *What* exactly do you want to generalize? How will you tell if a proposed generalization is *good*? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: In any case the question should restrict to the case of *commutative* rings. I suppose you want your operator to be at least $R$-linear, which means that is commutes with all scalar multiplications by elements of $R$. However if $k$ is not in the center of $R$, then multiplication by $k$ does not have this property, so there is no hope of finding any solutions for such $k$.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen, why is there no hope of finding [such solutions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81768/generalization-of-eigenvalues-vectors-to-modules#comment209861_81768)?  That multiplication by $k$ is not linear surely doesn't mean that we can't ask for solutions of $Ov = k v$ for linear $O$ (any more than non-linearity of a quadratic form $q$ means that we can't ask for solutions to $Lv = qv$).

Comment: @LSpice: I'm not saying you cannot pose or solve the equation ($v=0$ always works), but it is not very interesting. You would like to find a nonzero sub-module $M$ on which $O$ acts like multiplication by a scalar $k$. This means that for all $r\in R$ and $m\in M$ one requires $(kr)m=k(rm)=O(rm)=r(Om)=r(km)=(rk)m$ so the sumodule must be annihilated by $kr-rk$ for all $r$; this is very restrictive.

Answer (score 8):

There is another way to look at this. Let $K$ be a commutative ring and $M$ a $K$-module.
Then giving a $K$-linear endomorphism of $M$ is equivalent to an action of the polynomial ring $K[x]$ on $M$. Then the question becomes: what is the structure of $M$ as a $K[T]$-module? The classification of finitely generated $K[x]$-modules in the case $K$ is a field is a well-known result that used to be taught to undergraduates.

Comment: I would go so far as to say that the correct generalization of an eigenvalue is an irreducible $K[T]$-module, whatever those turn out to be for a particular $K$. For instance, this is one way to interpret why we can talk about the complex eigenvalues of a real matrix.

Comment: @Will Yes, exactly. You also need to think about whether you want the irreducible representations that occur as composition factors or whether you want the decomposition into indecomposable modules.

Answer (score 6):

In the case of commutative rings, you can view spectra as points in the quotient of $End_R(M)$ by the conjugation action of $Aut_R(M)$.  You can use the tensor product to turn this into a quotient of a scheme by a group.  If $M$ is locally free of rank $n$, the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial (say, viewed as traces of $\wedge^i O$ on $\wedge^i M$) give you a map to affine $n$-space over the spectrum of $R$.  You can think of this as a space of elementary symmetric polynomials in eigenvalues.  If you take your operator $O \in End_R(M)$, and send it to a point in this space, I suppose an eigenvalue is what you get by lifting to an element in the $S_n$-orbit in the affine space of roots, and projecting to a coordinate.  These don't exist globally.

This sort of construction arises when studying the Hitchin map.

(Minor comment: Darij's claim that the eigenvalue map is discontinuous uses an implicit assumption that the set with three elements should be endowed with the discrete topology.)

Comment: Hmm, I'll need to think about that.  Thank you!

Comment: @darijgrinberg's claim that the eigenvalue (I think rather Jordan-form) map is discontinuous:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81768/generalization-of-eigenvalues-vectors-to-modules#comment209779_81770 .

Answer (score 2):

This just means that the submodule generated by $v$, i.e. $\lbrace rv\mid r\in R\rbrace$, is invariant with respect to the operator $O$ (which acts rather in the module than the ring $R$), no more.

Comment: But one could say the same thing about eigenvectors:  they are just one-dimensional linear subspaces that happen to be invariant under the action of O and not more.  And yet there has been a great body of theory with all sorts of interesting results with practical applications developed about them.  Is there really no analogous body of theory for modules, or perhaps modules with some additional structure such as a dot product and norm?

Comment: I think you won't have a good theory mainly because the theory of eigenvalues and eigenvectors is uncontinuous/unfunctorial. Let me try to clarify this on the example of the Jordan normal form of a $2\times 2$ matrix. It can have three different forms: either a diagonal matrix with distinct elements on the diagonal, in which case the diagonalization is essentially unique (i. e., every eigenvalue has only one eigenvector up to scalar multiplication), or a diagonal matrix with equal elements on the diagonal, in which case the diagonalization gives a lot of freedom (because the matrix we ...

Comment: ... are diagonalizing is a scalar multiple of the unity matrix), or a Jordan block, in which case we have more freedom than in the first but less freedom than in the second case. So the Jordan form gives us a map from the matrix ring $\mathrm M_2\left(k\right)$ into the three-element set $\left\{1,2,3\right\}$, which simply says what case we are in. Now, this map is highly un-continuous, and there is a yoga that uncontinuous maps can only rarely be reasonably defined over rings. For example, what is the "rank" of a matrix over a ring? You can define it as the maximum $r$ for which the ...

Comment: ... matrix has a nonvanishing $r\times r$ minor, but much of the rank theory that was easy over rings becomes harder here. Basically, there is nothing interesting to say about matrices of rank $m$ over a ring; still there are theorems about matrices of rank $\leq m$ over a ring, since rank is, while not continuous, at least semicontinuous. As for combinatorial properties of the Jordan normal form, I guess they are not even semicontinuous, so we shouldn't expect much to hold here.

Comment: What IS possible for a general ring is to adjoin the "formal" eigenvalues of a matrix to the ring. By "formal" eigenvalues, I just mean the roots of the characteristic polynomial. This is possible because the characteristic polynomial is monic. The ring extension that will contain these roots will be a free module over the ring of rank $n!$, where $n$ is the degree of the characteristic polynomial (i. e., the size of the matrix). I can go into details if you are interested in that. But the eigenvalues-eigenvectors relation breaks down, since in the case of fields it relies on the ...

Comment: ... eigenvector being nonzero, while in the case of rings being-nonzero is not enough to keep the monsters at bay (there are many things "very close to $0$", such as nilpotents), whereas requiring the eigenvector to be primitive (i. e., its coordinates generating the unit ideal) might already be too restrictive. Again, this is an example of how a non-continuous notion (that of being nonzero) breaks down when we pass from fields to rings.

Comment: Little correction: My map to $\left\{1,2,3\right\}$ *is* semicontinuous for an appropriate order; but I am pretty sure that any map sending matrices to their Jordan normal forms is not.

Comment: After all the ramblings, here is maybe something more direct: Even if your module is free, eigenspaces of eigenvectors need not be free modules, so you cannot really speak about their "dimensions".

Comment: Hmm, I'll need to chew on that for a while.  Thanks a lot!  :-)

Comment: @Darij: that seems long enough that you could write it up as an answer, for better visibility

Comment: Long enough, but not substantial enough (the only actual mathematical assertion is my last comment).

Comment: Actually, understanding that the much of the theory of eignenvales and eigenspaces assumes that one is working with a free modules with the feature that all of its submodules are also free gave me an incredibly helpful starting point, so thank you.  :-)

Comment: *All* of the theory of eigenvalues and eigenspaces assumes that one is working over a field. 

Comment: I suppose a better way of phrasing my point is that it would seem that much of the structure that arises in eigenvalue theory specifically is making use of the fact that all of the submodules of a vector space are free, so if this does not property hold for a given module then it makes it unlikely that one could find analogies to the nice structure of eigenvalues/eigenspaces in said module.

Comment: All submodules of a projective module are projective, and projective modules are not too bad - they seem to be the right place to develop the theory of inner product spaces over rings, for instance.

Comment: @Will Sawin: of course it is not true that all submodules of a projective module are projective - otherwise there would be almost no Tor and Ext functors in nature!!!